# Conflicts between unittest and nose frameworks

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, nose

Nose [supports test generators](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators). But the documentation says:

> Please note that method generators are not supported in
>   unittest.TestCase subclasses

This means all my test generators must be outside of `unittest` framework.

Question: should I still use the `unittest` framework for those tests where I can? Or should I, for consistency reasons, abandon `unittest` entirely?

And why doesn't `nose` support test generators within `unittest.TestCase`? It seems to destroy the biggest advantage of `nose`: that it is an *extension* rather than a *replacement* for `unittest`, thus offering additional benefits without taking away any of the features provided by `unittest`. Or am I missing something?

And a related question. If I ditch `unittest` entirely, should I put my tests into global functions or into some new class hierarchy?

Comment: I needed something similar to test generators and ended up using [nose-parameterized](https://github.com/wolever/nose-parameterized). The decorator syntax was a lot cleaner, and it worked with `unittest.TestCase`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In nose, the lack of support for funkier kinds of tests in unittest.TestCases is intentional -- the idea was that nose should collect test from unittest.TestCases *exactly* as unittest does. Probably that was a bad idea, but it's very unlikely to change now.

So as long as you don't mind being a bit out on the bleeding edge, I'd suggest trying nose2. nose2 doesn't discriminate and supports all kinds of test plugins for all kinds of tests. Docs are on rtd: http://nose2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html, downloads on pypi: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose2/0.4.1.